# storyboard instantiating view controllers, crashes

Tags: ios, ios5, uistoryboard

I have created a project in iOS5 with storyboard. I dragged a UIViewController onto the canvas, set the identifier and the custom class . When I try to use this method , the code crashes on this line. I am not able to figure out, why?

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Contacts"];
```

Comment: What error message are you getting when it crashes? Also, where did you put this line of code?

Comment: sigabrt, i put this line in a button action method,

Comment: @zahreelay If you write the complete error we can know what is happening, You can see it on the lower part. especially since its a sigabrt which are very descriptive errors that tell you that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: its not telling anything, i hust get SIGABRT and it crashes.

Comment: downvotes are not helping, if you understand the problem , please help, else dont just come and downvote

Comment: As most have said this needs more detail for us to help. However, I have a few resources that might help you, General Storyboard Tutorial:- http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219, Loading a view from the Storyboard:- http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=256 this second one shows you exactly how to load a view from a storyboard. If you can give us more info maybe we can help with your problem more. Good luck hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> An identifier string that uniquely identifies the view controller in
>   the storyboard file. You set the identifier for a given view
>   controller in Interface Builder when configuring the storyboard file.
>   This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself
>   and is only used by the storyboard file to locate the view controller.
>
> **If the specified identifier does not exist (or is nil) in the storyboard file, this method raises an exception.**

Are u sure the identifier is the same?

EDIT:

The structure to do this should be something like this

```
UIViewController *temp = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePickerViewController"];

[self presentModalViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

And for that viewcontroller on the storyboard, under the show the attributes inspector -> viewcontroller -> identifier -> "ImagePickerViewController"

Comment: actually why are you using that method? do you have a vc in your storyboard that will present another one?

Comment: yes, i am using that line in a button action method, after instantiating the view controller, I have to add it as a subview to another view controller.

Comment: do we have to do any additional setup from storyboard, so that the identifier is not nil?

Comment: no, but just to be sure that THIS line is the one causing trouble, add a breakpoint before and after this line.

Comment: i have already done that, that's why i am telling its crashing on this line

Comment: check the edit, that is how i do it and it works perfectly fine. Unless you track the error to a function call or something i cant help you further...